# How to add precision to decimal value

Tags: c#, decimal, decimal-point

I want to add precision to the decimal value. For example, I have this value:

```
decimal number = 10;
```

I want to make it `10.00`. I don't want to convert it to `string` like `number.ToString("#.00")`

Currently, I have this method:

```
decimal CalculatePrecision(decimal value, int precision)
{
    var storedCalculated = decimal.Divide(1, Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Pow(10, precision)));
    return value + storedCalculated - storedCalculated;
}
```

Is there any good solution for this?

Comment: Can you explain why you think you want this?

Comment: @Silvermind, I need this on the deserializing process. When it is 10 without points, it looks like an integer, but it is decimal type

Comment: I need to put some logic on setting property

Comment: Many solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164926/how-do-i-display-a-decimal-value-to-2-decimal-places

Comment: Some serializers support decorating your properties with conversion attributes that are used when the object is serialized.

Comment: How do you serialize the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. 10 and 10.00 are the same number. Only the "presentation" is different. Both "presentations" are strings. The actual number look different. If you need to change the presentation, convert to string.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
 decimal d = 10;
 d += 0.00M;
 Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Try reference

[Math.Round not keeping the trailing zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307630/math-round-not-keeping-the-trailing-zero)

[How do I display a decimal value to 2 decimal places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164926/how-do-i-display-a-decimal-value-to-2-decimal-places)